# Getter returning NULL c#

Tags: c#, getter-setter

When accessing the property using the getter i'm getting a NULL. I've changed it to public to test if everything else is working and yeah nothing else is wrong.

> HTProvince Class

```
public string provinceCode;

public string ProvinceCode
{
    get; set;
}
```

> Form

```
public Form1()
{
    //HTGetProvinces() returns a list of provinces
    InitializeComponent();
    List<HTProvince> provinceList =
        HTProvince.HTGetProvinces();

    foreach (HTProvince x in provinceList)
    {
        //Works. Adds items the province code property of for each item to my list
        provincesListBox.Items.Add(x.provinceCode); 
        //throws null exception. Doesn't work
        provincesListBox.Items.Add(x.ProvinceCode);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is null because you never set a value for that property.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is auto-properties introduced in C# 3.0 and later

Change the property to:

```
private string provinceCode { get; set; }
```

Instead of a separate method:

```
public string ProvinceCode
{
    get; set;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That is right behaviour, you have not return any value for this property or set value so it is `null`.

```
public string ProvinceCode
{
    get; set;
}
```

if you want to return the provinceCode

```
private string provinceCode;
public string ProvinceCode
{
    get 
    {
    return provinceCode;
    }
    set 
    {
    provinceCode = value;
    }     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That is a bad practice. You have to make your field 'provinceCode' to private

```
private string provinceCode;
```

Your property has to be only public
Which can only be access.

```
public string ProvinceCode
  {
    get 
     {
        return provinceCode;
     }
   set 
    {
       provinceCode = value;
    }     
 }


public Form1()
{
    //HTGetProvinces() returns a list of provinces
    InitializeComponent();
    List<HTProvince> provinceList =
        HTProvince.HTGetProvinces();

    foreach (HTProvince x in provinceList)
    {
        //Works. Adds items the province code property of for each item to my list
        provincesListBox.Items.Add(x.ProvinceCode); 

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have some default value if ProvinceCode is not set you could use lazy loading:

```
private string _provinceCode;
public string ProvinceCode
{
    get 
    {
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(_provinceCode)) {
        _provinceCode = "CODE";
    }
    return _provinceCode;
    }
    set 
    {
        _provinceCode = value;
    }     
}
```